# "Undefined Index" PHP errors after upgrade from 1.6 to 2.9

Tags: custom-fields, fieldtype, upgrade, php-errors

After upgrading from 1.6 to 2.9, I’m getting a set of the errors below when displaying a page containing images, one set for each image. I’m running PHP 5.4.x and it says “Fast CGI” after the 5.4.x.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: upload_date
Filename: file/ft.file.php
Line Number: 303

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: modified_date
Filename: file/ft.file.php
Line Number: 304
```

I also had Mark Huot’s File extension running in 1.6. I “resubmitted” or updated the field type for one custom field as “File” and I also ran the fix in this thread on this one custom file field, but only the part regarding the line breaks:

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/218268/

and to see those in my template, I have to use the tag pair, or else nothing is output:

```
{myFileFieldName}{url}{/myFileFieldName}
```

I didn’t run the part about including the file directory, because EE is not parsing my {filedir_x} tag.

In all other cases of file fields, where I didn’t run the fix or update/resubmit the custom field type as File, I can get output by just using the stand-alone tag, but I still get the errors:

```
{myFileFieldName}
```

UPDATE:

I did some more digging. So this error/warning is taking place at lines 303 and 304 of expressionengine/fieldtypes/file/ft.file.php in a function called:

```
replace_tag($file_info, $params = array(), $tagdata = FALSE)
```

and here’s where it chokes in that function:

```
$date_vars = array(
   'upload_date' => $file_info['upload_date'],
   'modified_date' => $file_info['modified_date']
);
```

I know next to nothing about PHP, but I reckon $file_info has a problem, so I did an echo on $file_info and it returns what looks like just a string: “Array”.

Not sure where to go from here to fix that. The upload_date and modified_date columns in exp_files table are filled with data, so I can't imagine what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do two things to resolve the issue:

1. Apply both steps (adding the {filedir_x} and searching replacing new lines/line breaks) of the fix from this EllisLab forum thread across the board, to all File fields not just to one File field:
   https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/218268/
2. I went into the Admin for channel fields and re-submitted each custom field that was a File field type.

Something about that exercise appears to have fixed the issue. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to "re-sync" your files to force EE to generate the date data that it's looking for.

In the control panel, navigate to `Content ‣ Files ‣ File Upload Preferences ‣ Synchronize Files`.

Complete details are in the EE docs here:
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/sync_files.html

> The Synchronize Files page allows you to synchronize the file records
>   in the database with the files stored in a given upload directory.
>   When submitted, all allowed file types in the directory will be
>   checked against the file records in the database. If there is no
>   record in the database, one will be added. For images, any additional
>   sizes will be generated and watermarked according to the file upload
>   preferences for that directory. Lastly, any records in the database
>   that do not have a corresponding file in the main directory will be
>   deleted from the database along with any existing resized images.
>   Existing images may also be set to regenerate resized images from this
>   page.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. It turned out to be something else, which I'll post in a moment. But your suggestions helped me figure it out.